# PHP variadic functions before and after PHP 5.6

Tags: php, variadic-functions

I would like understand if the variadic functions in php are implemented like in the code below?

Considering that I'm using PHP7 so my question is: I don't need func_get_args(), func_get_arg() and  func_num_args() ?

```
<?php
// variadic function in PHP >= 5.6
function foo1(...$d){
    return var_dump($d);
}

echo foo1("a", "b", 1);
?>

<hr>

<?php
// variadic function in PHP < 5.6
function foo2(){
    $d = func_get_args();
    return var_dump($d);
}

echo foo1("a", "b", 1);
?>
```

Comment: No you don't since vararg $d will be an array .... why are you echoing a func that already var_dump the param?

Comment: @koalaok thanks!
About echoing, you're right!